# Python "local variable referenced before assignment" Error despite Global key

Tags: python, variables, global, local

here is my problem:

```
savedFileSize = 0
savedFileCount = 0
SUBFOLDER = False

def saveFile(path, filename):
    global savedFileSize
    global savedFileCount

    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if SUBFOLDER:
        try:
            subpath = os.path.join(SAVEPATH, path.split("\\", 1)[1])
            if not os.path.exists(subpath):
                os.makedirs(subpath)
            shutil.copy(filepath, subpath)
            savedFileCount += 1
            savedFileSize += os.path.getsize(filepath)/(1024*1024)
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.exception(e)
    else:
        try:
            shutil.copy(filepath, SAVEPATH)
            savedFileCount += 1
            savedFileSize += os.path.getsize(filepath)/(1024*1024)
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.exception(e)
```

I get the "local variable 'savedFileCount' referenced before assignment" Error the whole time.
But the variable SUBFOLDER works without any Problems.
Also the savedFileSize variable works without any problems.

Comment: Not possible, try to re-run your code.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe you have to call the function to initialize the variables in it. I also don't get any errors when I run the code, nothing happens but I get a system.ext(0)

Comment: In case you're running this code from shell using imports then try to get rid of any old .pyc files if you've any.

Comment: Thanks  Ashwini Chaudhary for you solution. I deleted the old .pyc files and everything is running fine! I cant believe this was the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad that deleting your pyc files solved your problem. However, your code doesn't actually call for global variables. In most of the cases the (evitable) use of globals is a sign of not so good design and may cause all sorts of problems, including name clashes etc.

You could refactor easily your code without globals:

```
def saveFile(path, filename):
    savedFileCount, savedFileSize = 0, 0
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if SUBFOLDER:
        try:
            subpath = os.path.join(SAVEPATH, path.split("\\", 1)[1])
            if not os.path.exists(subpath):
                os.makedirs(subpath)
            shutil.copy(filepath, subpath)
            savedFileCount = 1
            savedFileSize = os.path.getsize(filepath)/(1024*1024)
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.exception(e)
    else:
        try:
            shutil.copy(filepath, SAVEPATH)
            savedFileCount = 1
            savedFileSize += os.path.getsize(filepath)/(1024*1024)
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.exception(e)
    return savedFileCount, savedFileSize
```

And then in your calling scope:

```
totalCount, totalSize = 0
for path, filename in tobesaved:
    count, size = saveFile(path, filename)
    totalCount += count
    totalSize += size
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks alot cleaner!